# Добрый день! Не получается решить задачу. Неделя как я начал изучать Питон и зашел в тупик

Tags: python

Необходимо решить 2ую часть задачи: 1ая часть:

> "По данному натуральному n<=9 выведите лесенку из n-ступенек, i-я
>   ступенька состоит из чисел от 1 до i без пробела";

2ая часть:

> "теперь нужно дополнить 1ую часть, чтобы получалась пирамида и каждая
>   ступень состояла из чисел от 1 до i и обратно"

1ую часть решил вот так:

```
n = int(input())
x = ""
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    x = x + str(i)
    print(x)
```

На выходе при вводе 3, 1ая часть задачи выполняется корректно:

```
1
12
123
```

Теперь требуется, чтобы при вводе 3, исходя из 2ой части задачи, получилось:

```
  1
 121
12321
```

Не могу понять логику, учитывая, что по курсу пока изучены только операторы и циклы, ф-ции print, range, str.

Огромная просьба помочь в написании кода, т.к. уже 3й день не могу решить
Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно даже сам код особо не менять, только print изменить:

```
n = int(input())
x = ""
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    x = x + str(i)
    print(' ' * (n-i) + x + x[-2::-1])  # <- Изменил эту строку
```

Comment: У вас выглядит проще, мне нравится :)

Comment: А каким образом отступы в каждой строке добавить, чтобы получалась именно  пирамида?

Answer (score 0):

Накидал пример:

```
n = 9

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    left = ''.join(map(str, range(1, i)))
    spaces = ' ' * (n - i)
    print(f'{spaces}{left}{i}{left[::-1]}')

#         1
#        121
#       12321
#      1234321
#     123454321
#    12345654321
#   1234567654321
#  123456787654321
# 12345678987654321
```

Comment: А возможно  решить данную задачу, используя только цикл for, ф-цию print и str?

Comment: @SvSavikov, можно в другом ответе так и сделано :)

Comment: согласен, но при этом отступы как-то добавить требуется для пирамиды как у вас

Comment: @SvSavikov, в том ответе отступы слева добавляются за счет `' ' * (n-i)`

Comment: на выходе все-равно лесенка, пирамида не получается как у вас

Comment: @SvSavikov, вы что-то не так делаете, ибо код того ответа работает: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/576c519f634eebeff75fc23e9e94a4f73f2cc344/digital_pyramid.py#L27

Comment: что-то не так оказалось заводил n-1всем спасибо огромное,